# UITableView When button pressed

Tags: iphone

Iam trying for a dropdown list .since there is no direct tool for drop down list in iphone, i thought of keeping UITableView .When the button is pressed the tableView Should appear ,when the cursor is clicked on the free space it should be disappeared.Since iam using more than three buttons the single UITableView should be reused.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd stick to the native UI elements if at all possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its best to use Settings like UI (when you select language or something from a populated list) instead of drop down, which is easy to use and follows the Apple guidelines too...

though you can make dropdown type ui also in iPhone by adding tableview in your main view based on button event and when user selects some option then remove from your main view.